# React native view shot can't receive empty message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-view-shot

I want to export the image using React Native View Shot, but there is a problem, how come the image doesn't want to export, so there's an error like this. In English, it's like "shot can't receive empty message"
[image]

this is my code

```js
import ViewShot, { captureScreen } from 'react-native-view-shot';
const viewShotRef = useRef();
const [handleButton, setHandleButton] = useState(true);

async function captureViewShot() {
  setHandleButton(false);
  const imageURI = await viewShotRef.current.capture();
  console.log(imageURI);
  setHandleButton(true);
  Share.share({ title: 'Nota', url: imageURI });
}

function captureScreenShot() {
  captureScreen({
    format: 'jpg',
    quality: 0.8,
  }).then(
    (uri) => {
      console.log(uri);
      Share.share({ title: 'Nota', url: uri });
    },
    (error) => console.log('IMage gagal to', error)
  );
}
```

and this is my viewshot

```
<ViewShot
  ref={viewShotRef}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  options={{ format: 'jpg', quality: 1.0 }}>
  <Table borderStyle={styles.tableStyle}>
    <Row
      data={tableHead}
      style={styles.head}
      textStyle={styles.text}
      flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]}
    />
    <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text} flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]} />
  </Table>
</ViewShot>
```

in my case I need 2 exports, namely export only the table and export the whole screen but neither of them works